# Saving Unity mesh created from Tango's Meshbuilder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I want to be able to save the mesh I generate from the Unity mesh builder. From what I can tell the way most people save is with the point cloud data however, I would much rather have the mesh that is generated inside Unity or data so I can recreate the mesh generated in Unity . When I looked into some of the scripts I found a few scripts that seem to deal with the data that is involved with the mesh

---

CustomPointCloudListener.cs

DynamicMeshCube.cs

DynamicMeshManager.cs

Polygonizer.cs

Voxel.cs

VoxelHashTree.cs

https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/tree/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoExamples/ExperimentalMeshBuilder/Scripts

---

What would be the best way of getting the mesh? I was thinking of trying to save the data by modifying one of the scripts above but I'm not sure where to even start with this.

Edit: the main reason I don't want cloud point data is because I would have to run it through something like this
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7028/wrapping-a-mesh-around-point-cloud-with-cavities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to look at the calls into the polygonizer, which is using  enhanced marching cubes  to extracting the surface.  Work back from there to get your mesh (sorry, doing this from memory, don't have the code in front of me)

Comment: Thanks, when I looked into the polygonizer's code I found the marching cubes algorithm and tried to figure out it is a little much for me but I will try to figure it out from here.

Comment: You're about to go waaaaaaaaay down the rabbit hole.  Note that current wisdom is to prefer 'dual contouring' over marching cubes, but if you've never met a Hermite before, this may not be the place to start  :-)  But do be aware the entire point of enhanced marching cubes is to try and get the stupid thing to stop rounding off corners  :-)   BTW, they keep score here - if you liked the answer, please do mark it accepted.